# Why is my code causing a I/O 104 error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This program raises an I/O 104 error on `EoF` when first entering the while loop.

The purpose of the program is to look up if a username is already taken. The existing usernames are stored in a text file.

```
procedure TForm1.btnRegisterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sCUser := edtUserName.Text;
  AssignFile(tNames, 'Names.txt');
  begin
    try
      Reset(tNames);
    except
      ShowMessage('File not found');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  rewrite(tNames);
  while not EoF(tNames) do // I get a I/O 104 Error here `
  begin
    Readln(tNames, sLine);
    iPosComme := Pos(',', sLine);
    sUser     := Copy(sLine, 1, iPosComme - 1);
    Delete(sLine, 1, iPosComme - 1);
    if sCUser = sUser then begin
      ShowMessage('Username taken');
    end
    else
    begin
      rewrite(tNames);
      Writeln(tNames, sCUser + ',' + '0');
      CloseFile(tNames);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should use `TIniFile`.

Comment: @Roberts: INI file does not solves the problem at all.

Comment: @Krom Stern I didn't say that it's going to solve the problem =P

Comment: @Roberts: Would be good to hear your reasoning still, why not xml or sql db for example ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Remove the call to `Rewrite()`before `Eof()`. Even if you were not getting an IO error, your code would still fail because `Rewrite()` closes the file you opened with `Reset()` and then it creates a new bank file, so `Eof()` would always be True.

**Update**: [error 104](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/delphiioerrors_xml.html) is `file not open for input`, which means `Reset()` is not opening the file but is not raising an exception (which sounds like an RTL bug if `Eof()` is raising an exception, indicating that `{I+}` is active).

In any case, using `AssignFile()` and related routines is the old way to do file I/O.  You should use newer techniques, like `FileOpen()` with `FileRead()`, `TFileStream` with `TStreamReader`, `TStringList`, etc...

**Update**: your loop logic is wrong. You are comparing only the first line. If it does not match the user, you are wiping out the file, writing the user to a new file, **closing the file**, and then continuing the loop. `EoF()` will then fail at that point. You need to rewrite your loop to the following:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRegisterClick(Sender: TObject
var
  SCUser, sUser: String;
  tNames: TextFile;
  iPosComme: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
begin
  sCUser := edtUserName.Text;
  AssignFile(tNames,'Names.txt');
  try
    Reset(tNames);
  except
    ShowMessage('File not found');
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    Found := False;
    while not EoF(tNames) do
    begin
      Readln(tNames,sLine);
      iPosComme := Pos(',', sLine);
      sUser := Copy(sLine ,1,iPosComme -1);
      if sCUser = sUser then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Username taken') ;
        Found := True;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    if not Found then
      Writeln(tNames,sCUser + ',0');
  finally
    CloseFile(tNames);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I removed it butt still get the I/O error. I even put in a simple 'username' into the textfile after the reset, but still didnt work

Comment: As suggested by Remy: throw away the old file access stuff and have a look at more up-to-date concepts like streams, etc. The old way is probably left in just for compatibility reasons (I don't know this for a fact, hence the "probably"). It is rarely used in today's code, and (IMHO) dealing with IoResult and $I+/- is just a PITA. Especially IoResult has very interesting semantics that can cause headaches to the unexperienced.

Comment: @DévanSteyn: I updated my answer. You are calling `Eof()` after closing the file, which will cause error 104.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this Version works for me, but it is hard to guess what the code is intended to do. Especially the while loop seems a bit displaced, since the file will contain exactly one line after the rewrite-case has ben hit once.

```
program wtf;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$I+}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure Sample( sCUser : string);
var sUser, sLine : string;
    iPosComme : Integer;
    tnames : textfile;
begin
  AssignFile(tNames,'Names.txt');

  try
    Reset(tNames);
  except
    Writeln('File not found');
    Exit;
  end;

  while not EoF(tNames) do
  begin
    Readln(tNames,sLine);
    iPosComme := Pos(',', sLine);
    sUser := Copy(sLine ,1,iPosComme -1);
    Delete( sLine,1, iPosComme -1);
    if sCuser = sUser then begin
      Writeln('Username taken') ;
    end
    else begin
      Rewrite(tNames);
      Writeln(tNames,sCUser + ',' + '0');
      CloseFile(tNames);
      Break; // file has been overwritten and closed
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Sample('foobar');
  except
    on E: Exception do Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a version of this method that uses the newer `TStreamReader` and `TStreamWriter` classes.

This won't work with Delphi 7 of course, it's just to show how this could be done in newer versions of Delphi.

The code was heavily inspired by Remys answer.

```
procedure TForm1.btnRegisterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TStream;
  Reader: TStreamReader;
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
  Columns: TStringList;
  UserName: string;
  Found: Boolean;
  FileName: string;
  Encoding: TEncoding;
begin
  FileName := ExpandFileName('Names.txt'); // An absolute path would be even better
  UserName := edtUsername.Text;
  Found    := False;
  Encoding := TEncoding.Default; // or another encoding, e.g. TEncoding.Unicode for Unicode
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Reader := TStreamReader.Create(Stream, Encoding);
    try
      Columns := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Columns.Delimiter := ',';
        Columns.StrictDelimiter := True; // or False, depending on the file format
        while not Reader.EndOfStream do
        begin
          Columns.DelimitedText := Reader.ReadLine;
          if Columns.Count > 0 then 
          begin
            if AnsiSameStr(Columns[0], UserName) then // or AnsiSameText if UserName is not case-sensitive
            begin
              ShowMessage('Username taken') ;
              Found := True;
              Break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Columns.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Reader.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  if not Found then
  begin
    Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(FileName, True, Encoding);
    try
      // Warning: This will cause problems when the file does not end with a new line
      Writer.WriteLine(UserName + ',0');
    finally
      Writer.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If performance and memory usage are not a concern:

```
procedure TForm1.btnRegisterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rows: TStringList;
  Columns: TStringList;
  UserName: string;
  Found: Boolean;
  FileName: string;
  Encoding: TEncoding;
  Row: string;
begin
  FileName := ExpandFileName('Names.txt'); // An absolute path would be even better
  UserName := edtUsername.Text;
  Found    := False;
  Encoding := TEncoding.Default; // or another encoding, e.g. TEncoding.Unicode for Unicode
  Rows := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Rows.LoadFromFile(FileName, Encoding);
    Columns := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Columns.Delimiter := ',';
      Columns.StrictDelimiter := True; // or False, depending on the file format
      for Row in Rows do
      begin
        Columns.DelimitedText := Row;
        if Columns.Count > 0 then
        begin
          if AnsiSameStr(Columns[0], UserName) then // or AnsiSameText if UserName is not case-sensitive
          begin
            ShowMessage('Username taken') ;
            Found := True;
            Break;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Columns.Free;
    end;
    if not Found then
    begin
      Rows.Add(UserName + ',0');
      Rows.SaveToFile(FileName, Encoding);
    end;
  finally
    Rows.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This solution can be adapted to Delphi 7 by removing the `Encoding` variable.

If it's part of a bigger database it should be stored in a real database management system rather than a text file.